# VB .NET COMBOBOX ValueMember

Tags: database, vb.net, combobox, valuemember

Hi guys I have problem with ValueMember. Look on code :

```
   conn.ConnectionString = _
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & _
"c:\\magazyn.mdb"
    ' Try
    conn.Open()

    da2 = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, conn)

    da2.Fill(ds2)
    ' DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Nazwa")
    ' DataGridView1.Update()
    ComboBox4.DataSource = Nothing

    ComboBox4.DataSource = ds2.Tables(0)

    ComboBox4.ValueMember = Nothing
    ComboBox4.DisplayMember = "Nazwa_Towaru"
    ComboBox4.ValueMember = "Kod_Towaru"

    MessageBox.Show(ComboBox4.Text + "-" + ComboBox4.ValueMember)

    ' Catch ex As Exception
    'MessageBox.Show("Brak podłączonej bazy/problem z podłączeniem do bazy")
    '  Finally
    conn.Close()
    '  End Try
```

MessageBox should show  me somthing like this  : Graphic Card   -   123ASD    first element is "Nazwa_Towaru" second is "Kod_Towaru"  but MB show me somthing like this : Graphic Card - "Kod_Towaru".   First time  I think  "Kod_Towaru" column in DATASET is empty but i check this and   column is with data .

I have also another ComboBox  with this same code and its work great so why this one not. ALL variables are local so they no colidate.

Comment: SOLVED -.- I must buy  glasses . MessageBox.Show(ComboBox4.Text + "-" + ComboBox4.SelectedValue)

Comment: Please show minimum effort of work by searching online or on this website before posting. Someone could down-vote your question... If you have the answer, you could close it then.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that ComboBox4.SelectedIndex = -1. After binding your combo box with a data source, set the selected index to 0 (if there are data in the combo box)

Serge